# How can I get an object from ressourceManager without being case sensitive?

Tags: c#

I need to get a bitmap image from the ressource and i'm accessing it via RessourceManager like this:

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("myImage");
```

The problem is that it's case sensitive and i don't want it to be case sensitive. Is it possible to ignore case sensitive when doing getObject?

Comment: Are you doing something dynamic? Resources are typically something static (like an image) that is known at build time and easy to reference with tooling. What's your scenario?

Comment: @GlennFerrie Yes, my app model is generated dynamicly and entities in that model have a text reference to images. So i'm not really aware what entity i'm building. All i know is that the images are in my ressources and the model is supposed to reference those images.

Comment: If your code is creating named resources, shouldn't you have 1st hand access to the resources exact case-sensitive name?

Comment: @GlennFerrie I can access them with Ressources.MyImage. The problem is that the first thing i noticed in the model is that an image was named all in lower case, but the .bmp i received is camel case. And since the model is dynamic i don't know what's the exact entity i'm building and what image i should use for its icon in the view. I'm only the programmer, the model was built by the database admins and the images were made by some other department, and i'm in the middle with their naming problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried  setting [IgnoreCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.ignorecase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thank you! Wasn't aware of this.